# MVC Kendo Dropdownlist rendered with EditorFor has massive javascript related issues

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

This is fairly complex, so please bear with me.

Let me first say that I am very new to MVC. My experience in even the basics are minimal, but my overall development experience with .NET/C# is extensive. Point being, the solution may be simple and I just do not know it lol.

Now.. We have a massive app that uses "EditorTemplates" (Partial views) via `@Html.EditorFor()` rendering in order to render customized UI elements based on database content as needed.

Now... I was tasked with creating one of these elements, and due to the complexity of our system and how long it takes to load it just to test, I decided to first develop my UI/Logic in its own standalone view/controller.

The view consisted of 3 cascading Kendo dropdownlists which pull data from a method in the controller (which returns a list of class objects).

I got this working beautifully in a standalone view/controller.

Now... I ported the HTML and logic from the controller in to the partial view files in our "EditorTemplates" folder, and ran our app for the first time.

Immediately I get a javascript error

> "filterRabu2" is not defined.

Here is the associated code:

```
<label for="rabu2">Rabu2:</label>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("rabu2")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
          .OptionLabel("Select ...")
          .DataTextField("Name")
          .DataValueField("ID")
                  .DataSource(source =>
                  {
                      source.Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetRabu2", "Datasets")
                             .Data("filterRabu2");
                      })

                      .ServerFiltering(true);
                  })
            //.Enable(false)
          .AutoBind(false)
          .CascadeFrom("rabu1")
    )

<script>
    function filterRabu2() {
        return {
            rabu1: $("#rabu1").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Now... I got rid of that error by moving that function to a .js file that was already being included in the page.

But... when the dropdownlists render, the first one (which should be enabled and with data present), it appears to be disabled and is not clickable. I confirmed that our data access routine is being hit and returning a valid and populated list of data, just as it did (working) in the standalone view.

That's where I'm at... I can't get the DDLs to function, and the existence of that JS error leads me to theorize that JS is not being rendered or allowed to execute properly? I have no idea.

This is being rendered via the `@Html.EditorFor()` method from another partial view inside a loop which renders templates for data based on that data... it's quite complex... but I could really use a hand at figuring out whats going on.

Comment: Where is element `'#rabu1'` located?

Comment: It is there... this is a pretty big file so I just added a snippet to help show the issue, but did not want to add the whole thing here. rabu1 and rabu3 are all pretty much identical except for the method they call to retrieve data. The point I was trying to make with this was that the javascript method was not being found. But if you read on even after solving that the problems continue :/

Comment: was this ever solved?  I am having a similar issue now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the dom is rendering before the the javascript has executed. Try wapping the calling method up in a

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        //initial method call here
});
```

This will ensure that the javascript executes after the dom has loaded.

Comment: Ya, I actually thought of that and tried it.. no luck. I am pretty sure its a limitation of @Html.EditorFor() thats stopping javascript inside the partial view from executing. But thinking that doesn't take me any closer to fixing it lol.